# Windows XP - very bright screen, weird colors, etc

Tags: windows, display

**Sorry if it's dumb question, I'm usually not using Windows and when I do I get stuck on easy things.**

I installed Windows XP... and colors are terrible. White is so bright that I can't look at the screen, everything looks weird. Any ideas how do I fix this *without changing settings on monitor panel itself* (current settings work ideal for me on Linux so I don't want to change them every time I boot into different system, heh)? I have CRT monitor.

Should I install nvidia driver or something? I usually do so on Linux but do Windows needs that too? Or maybe there are some settings for brightness and colors somewhere in OS itself? Generally - how to fix this by messing ONLY with software?

Again - sorry if it's dumb question...

Answer (score 1):

i have installed windows xp on several nvidia systems in the past and have not had this problem however i did some poking around and it is not unheard of.  Everything i have found is either a hardware problem or out of date driver.

Are you dual booting windows and Linux?  If you are and the monitor is fine in Linux you will almost certainly need to install the driver.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, then!

Answer (score 0):

So you have an Nvidia card, but didn't install the Windows Nvidia drivers? I would install the drivers. There's an Nvidia Control Panel with more color settings, but that may not be the problem you're seeing.

Too bad posting a screenshot wouldn't help. You could take a photo with a camera of the Linux and Windows though....

Right-click the desktop and choose Properties. Go to the Settings page (last tab). Set the resolution down to 800x600 (or even 640x480), if it's higher than that. Also on that page, it should mention what type of video adapter (card) Windows thinks it is. Is it right? If it's not there, you can try poking around the Advanced dialog.

Comment: Why should I set resolution to something low?

Comment: Standard resolutions are less likely to overdrive the card/monitor.